# Testing a theme in development

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

Some months ago I created a VSCode theme.
Now I would like to do some changes and I want to test it before publishing.

I didn't remember how I did it days before but on [VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#test-a-new-color-theme) I read that I have to press F5 to launch an Extension Development Host window and then `File > Preferences > Color Theme` and choose my theme in the drop-down list.

I tried. When I press F5 (fn + F5 on Mac), I get [image] and then? What I have to choose?

---

The location of `launch.json` is:

```
myTheme
|_ assets
|_ vscode
  |_ .vscode
    |_ launch.json
  |_ assets
  |_ themes
    |_ myTheme-color-theme.json
```

When I press f5:

[image]

where is the green triangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to the `Run/Debug` bar, open `launch.json` and add

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "extensionHost",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Extension",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
      "args": [
        "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Mmm thank you but it seems not to work. It's the same as before, nothing changes

Comment: @vila what is the location of the `launch.json` file and have you selected the correct config in the drop down box (next to the green triangle)

Comment: @vila The `.vscode` folder must be in the root of the workspace, not a subdir of `vscode`, the green triangle is at the top of the `Run/Debug` bar if you have a `launch.json` in the correct location